# Unable to Execute .py file

Tags: python

Even though I have python installed in my system. I'm unable to execute .py file. below is the error. Please assist.

> C:\Users\chandan\Desktop>py first.py
>   C:\Users\chandan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe:
>   can't open file 'first.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: A bit more info would be good: How are you executing (i.e. running) this python file, is it on the desktop?

Comment: to make things easier rename your file py_first.py and also pass on the full path of the file. Unless the file is on your desktop python is not going to see it. Sorry if that is obvious but you didn't provide any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

the file name should not contain any spaces. if you are using spaces use 
"" 
eg 
`python "py first.py"`